# How to write a link with complex content inside it so that it will be valid and correct

Tags: html, validation, w3c-validation, xhtml-1.0-strict

w3 html validator will tell me that this is wrong:

```
<a href="http://www.bla.com>
   <div>something</div>
   <ul>
       <li>first</li>
       <li>second</li>
   </ul>
</a>
```

in order to get a validated as HTML 4 strict (or just for writing things correctly)

What is the better way to write it:

1. no div's and ul's - just span's with classes that I need to design:

   `<a href="http://www.bla.com>`

   ```
     <span class="div">something</span>
      <span class="ul">
          <span class="li">first</span>
          <span class="li">second</span>
      </span>
   </a>
   ```
2. without `<a>`

`<div id="actAsLink" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.bla.com')>`

`<div>something</div>`

`<ul>`

```
   <li>first</li>
   <li>second</li>
```

`</ul>`

`</div>`

=========================

sorry that the code doesn't look at its best - I had troubles handling the "code sampler" on this website.

Comment: Code indention in Markdown: Four spaces before a block of code, and 4 additional spaced for each list-level. So, you will need 8 spaced before each line inside a level-1 list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I vote for option 1: Anchor + descriptive class names:

- The link will work, even when JavaScript or pop-ups are disabled. (this is the most **important** feature to me.)
- The class attributes describe their role, as a substitute for the `<ul>`, `<li>` elements. These elements can be styled using CSS.

Your structure looks a bit odd though: *Why do you want to nest a list in an anchor?*

Answer (score 1):

Really you should have `<a>` tags inside each of the `div`, `ul` and `li` tags:

```
<div><a href="#"></a></div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">first</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">second</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is valid markup, but obviously with the downside that you have three links instead of one. I'm not sure why you want to have a list inside a link though - it's more common to see a list of links.